# How to XZ a directory with TAR using maximum compression?

Tags: directory, tar, compression

So I need to compress a directory with max compression.

How can I do it with `xz`? I mean I will need `tar` too because I can't compress a directory with only `xz`. Is there a oneliner to produce e.g. `foo.tar.xz`?

Comment: FWIW, `man 1 xz` says `it's not a good idea to blindly use -9 for everything like it often is with gzip(1) and bzip2(1).` `-7 ... -9 [...]  These are useful only when compressing files bigger than 8 MiB, 16 MiB, and 32 MiB, respectively.` RTFM for more info.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Assuming `xz` honors the standard set of commandline flags - including compression level flags, you could try:

```
tar -cf - foo/ | xz -9 -c - > foo.tar.xz
```

Comment: and this uses maximum compression level with XZ?

Comment: `-9e` is the best level, but it will take very long

Comment: `-9e` will not always give you the best result - see point 8 here https://www.rootusers.com/13-simple-xz-examples/

Comment: Also, you might see significant improvement if you add `--threads=0` to xz

Comment: @KolonUK reading that article, it shows that `-e` (extreme mode) always improves compression ratio; the comparison is between `-0e` and `-6`; while `-e` always improves compression ratio within the same compression level, a higher compression level may be more effective than "extreme mode".  There is no evidence that `-9e` can yield a worse compression ratio than `-9`.

Answer (score 198):

With a recent GNU `tar` on bash or derived shell:

```
XZ_OPT=-9 tar cJf tarfile.tar.xz directory
```

tar's lowercase j switch uses bzip, uppercase J switch uses xz.

The `XZ_OPT` environment variable lets you set `xz` options that cannot be passed via calling applications such as `tar`.

This is now ***maximal***.

See `man xz` for other options you can set (`-e`/`--extreme` *might* give you some additional compression benefit for some datasets).

```
XZ_OPT=-e9 tar cJf tarfile.tar.xz directory
```

Comment: So to set both `-9` and `-e` xz opts, you want `XZ_OPT=-e9` but as @krzyk pointed out, -e is **extremely** slow

Comment: Its good to note, the use of XZ_OPT or XZ_DEFAULTS depends on the version of XZ and not TAR.  `man xz`

Comment: Just for the record: `XZ_OPT` is not a feature implemented in `tar`. It's a feature of `xz`. When `tar` calls `xz`, the env-variable is simply passed on.

Comment: `XZ_OPT=-e9T0 tar cJf tarfile.tar.xz directory`. T0 - Specify  the number of worker threads to use.  Setting threads to a special value 0 makes xz use as many threads as there are CPU cores on the system.

Comment: Double reminder to readers to check `man xz | grep XZ_OPT` *before* using this method.

Comment: @user3439968 - I wonder if using T0 without a space means compression level 0. I think using `XZ_OPT="-e9 -T 0" tar cJf tarfile.tar.xz directory` is what you mean.

Comment: @midnite not needed, works as @user3439968 said: `XZ_OPT=-9T0 tar cJf file.tar.xz file`

Answer (score 22):

```
XZ_OPT=-9e tar cJf tarfile.tar.xz directory
```

is even better than

```
XZ_OPT=-9 tar cJf tarfile.tar.xz directory
```

The option -e, "--extreme Modify the compression preset (-0 ... -9)" so that a little bit better compression ratio can be achieved without increasing memory usage of the compressor or decompressor (exception: compressor memory usage may increase a little with presets -0 ... -2). The downside is that the compression time will increase dramatically (it can easily double).

Comment: So, If i'm compressing about 80GB of Software on my machine (when i want all the computers resources to go to the compression process for speed) i should use `-9` not `-9e`, yeah?

Comment: xz by default uses 1 core/thread, you can max that out (speed it all up) by adding -T0, eg `XZ_OPT="-9e -T0" tar -cJf ...`

Answer (score 17):

If you have 16 GiB of RAM (and nothing else running), you can try:

```
tar -cf - foo/ | xz --lzma2=dict=1536Mi,nice=273 -c - > foo.tar.xz
```

This will need 1.5 GiB for decompression, and about 11x that for compression. Adjust accordingly for lesser amounts of memory.

This will only help if the data is actually that big, and in any case it won't help *THAT* much, but still...

If you're compressing binaries, add --x86 as the first xz option. If you're playing with "multimedia" files (uncompressed audio or bitmaps), you can try with --delta=dist=2 (experiment with value, good values to try are 1..4).

If you're feeling very adventurous, you can try playing with more LZMA options, like

```
--lzma2=dict=1536Mi,nice=273,lc=3,lp=0,pb=2
```

(these are the default settings, you can try values between 0 and 4, and lc+lp must not exceed 4)

In order to see how the default presets map to these values, you can check the source file src/liblzma/lzma/lzma_encoder_presets.c. Nothing of much interest there though (-e sets the nice length to 273 and also adjusts the depth).

Answer (score 8):

`tar --help` :  `-I, --use-compress-program=PROG`

```
tar -I 'xz -9' -cvf foo.tar.xz foo/  
tar -I 'gzip -9' -cvf foo.tar.gz foo/
```

also compress with external compressors:

```
tar -I 'lz4 -9' -cvf foo.tar.lz4 foo/
tar -I 'zstd -19' -cvf foo.tar.zst foo/
```

decompress external compressors:

```
tar -I lz4 -xvf foo.tar.lz4  
tar -I zstd -xvf foo.tar.zst
```

list archive external compressors:

```
tar -I lz4 -tvf foo.tar.lz4
tar -I zstd -tvf foo.tar.zst
```

Comment: This seems like a working answer, but, as it is, it would be greatly improved by having its formatting fixed and and explanation of option `-I` added.

Answer (score 7):

You might try different options, for me -4e works better

```
tar cf - wam_GG_${dir}.nc | xz -4e > wam_GG_${dir}.nc.tar.xz
```

I tested by running:

```
$ tar -cf - wam_GG.nc | xz -4e > wam_GG.nc.xz
$ tar -cf - wam_GG.nc | xz -9e > wam_GG.nc.xz.2
```

So, it seems that option -4e works a little bit better than -9e.

```
$ ll wam_GG.nc.xz*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 504 504 2707596 Jan 16  2015 wam_GG.nc.xz
-rw-rw-r--. 1 504 504 2708416 Jan 16  2015 wam_GG.nc.xz.2
```

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.  This is just an observation that for your particular small data set, -4e already gets the best compression and so the higher levels don't get any more benefit ( and even an ever so slight penalty ).

Comment: Are you the same user as [Szymon Roziewski](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/58294/szymon-roziewski)? If so, please don't post multiple answers. Instead, edit your original answer. If you can't access your first account, please see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to merge your accounts. In the meantime, I am deleting your previous answer and including it here.

Comment: Ok, I have done a more comprehensive study on that. What I got is here. I chose some files from my hardrive and made compression with option -4e and -9e. So, it's better to find your best solution by yourself. You were right, for some cases -9e is better whereas for another it's not:
`no difference = 660
4e better than 9e = 74
9e better than 4e = 17
total files = 751
tar 2
html 2
csv 2
xml 2
gz 2
ppt 2
eps 2
docx 2
gif 2
rpm 3
png 3
asv 3
xlsx 3
exe 3
rar 4
nc 4
txt 5
odt 6
xls 7
zip 7
doc 9
m 12
dat 17
other 109
pdf 133
 135
jpg 270
`

Comment: (comments may be edited only for 5 minutes)
`txt 109 
txt/pdf 135`

Answer (score 5):

`tar` command uses `J` flag for xz files. An example:

`tar -cJvf foo.tar.xz foo/`

Comment: The `J` was already mentioned in bdowning's answer

Answer (score 5):

In a multicore machine from version v5.2.0 of xz-utils, check:

```
-T, --threads=NUM   use at most NUM threads; the default is 1; set to 0
```

If you wish to use the maximum number of cores and maximum compression:

```
export XZ_DEFAULTS="-9 -T 0 "
```

Or set -T to the number of cores you wish to use.

Then:

```
tar cJf target.tar.xz source
```

Also this may useful in order to choose the compression level:

https://catchchallenger.first-world.info/wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO

Answer (score 3):

For those interested, `-e9` is 0.4% smaller, 20% slower at compression, 3% slower for decompression, compared to `-9` on a typical laptop. Here're the timing runs on the Python source code directory structure.

Compression:

```
$ Tbefore=`date +%s%3N` && XZ_OPT=-9 tar cJf python3.6.tar.9xz Python-3.6.0 && Tafter=`date +%s%3N`
$ python -c "print((float($Tafter) - float($Tbefore)) / 1000.)"
43.87
$ Tbefore=`date +%s%3N` && XZ_OPT=-e9 tar cJf python3.6.tar.e9xz Python-3.6.0 && Tafter=`date +%s%3N`
$ python -c "print((float($Tafter) - float($Tbefore)) / 1000.)"
53.861
```

Decompression:

```
$ Tbefore=`date +%s%3N` && tar xf python3.6.tar.9xz && Tafter=`date +%s%3N`
$ python -c "print((float($Tafter) - float($Tbefore)) / 1000.)"  && rm -rf Python-3.6.0
1.395
$ rm -rf Python-3.6.0
$ Tbefore=`date +%s%3N` && tar xf python3.6.tar.e9xz && Tafter=`date +%s%3N`
$ python -c "print((float($Tafter) - float($Tbefore)) / 1000.)"  && rm -rf Python-3.6.0
1.443
```

File Size:

```
$ rm -rf Python-3.6.0
$ Tbefore=`date +%s%3N` && tar xf Python-3.6.0.tar.xz && Tafter=`date +%s%3N`
$ python -c "print((float($Tafter) - float($Tbefore)) / 1000.)" && rm -rf Python-3.6.0
1.49
$ ls -al ?ython*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hobs hobs 16378500 Dec 23 13:06 python3.6.tar.9xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hobs hobs 16314420 Dec 23 13:05 python3.6.tar.e9xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hobs hobs 16805836 Dec 23 12:24 Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
```

Comment: Bad variable name choosing, because T0 is option to enable multi-threaded archivation.

Comment: @Dzenly You're right! Thank you! Changed it.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum compression depends on the capabilities of the equipment on which you want to apply it. Maximum compression results in a diametrical extension of its duration, generating a heavy load of hardware resources.  For this reason, it is not recommended to maximize the use of server resources **(CPU / RAM / Disk)** to not slow down the work of other services running on it. It is worth taking into account the compromise between the degree of compression and its duration/system load.

In my case, I used `xz` on a laptop (hence I used the maximum hardware capabilities) with maximally selected parameters – CPU threads, mem RAM limit and disk performance. I chose the compression level experimentally and it worked best (for me) with the **DictSize = 32 MiB** option. 
Below is the command used:

```
xz -k -8e -M 7000MB -T 8 -v sd-dump-rpi3b+-strech.img
```

where:

- `-k`  - compress
- `-8e` - compression level
- `-M`  - RAM usage limit (in GB)
- `-T`  - number of processor threads used
- `-v`  - verbose mode - show progress compressing data

This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuGgu.jpg) may be informative.

I deliberately did not use compression on the fly (no using pipe) because of the limitation of the reading speed from the SD memory on my laptop (max ~28 MB/s). 
I dumped the system image from the SD card to the SSD with the **dd** command:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/mmcblk0 > ~/Desktop/sd-dump-rpi3b+-strech.img
```

or optionally, fully using `dd` syntax:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=~/Desktop/sd-dump-rpi3b+-strech.img
```

and then compressed it. 
In this way, I bypassed the bottleneck of data transfer speed that is SD card
and I used the maximum: CPU threads, memory RAM and SSD (Read/Write ~540 MB/s).

It is worth considering the fact that the SD card used has a capacity of 32 GB,
the system uses ~3.6 GB on it. 
The card dump weighs ~29 GB before compression and ~1.7 GB after compression. 
The empty card space is ~28.4 GB, which was also compressed with ~3.6 GB of data – mainly binary files. Assuming 3.6 to 1.7 gives a little over 50% compression,
which is a satisfying effect with a compression time of ~15 minutes. 
I deliberately skipped free space compression,
because during this process I noticed a rapid reduction in compression time
from a first calculating ~45 minutes
and increased momentary use of the SSD up to ~266 MB/s (in impulse).

It is worth mentioning that at a high level of compression,
a large number of CPU threads (e.g., 8 threads at `-9e` for me)
and the amount of RAM not usable properly,
results in a reduction in the number of threads  xz
(not to exceed the declared memory usage limit).

Appropriate selection of the amount of RAM memory limit and CPU threads will allow you to maintain adequate performance and fast compression without exhausting hardware resources (CPU and RAM).

This is the hardware I used:

IdeaPad Z580

- i7-3632QM
- 2 x 4 GB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous PC3-12800 (1600 MHz)
- SSD IRSSDPRS25A120

Software:

- Debian Stretch (x86_64)
- Kernel 4.9.0-11-amd64
- xz (XZ Utils) 5.2.2
- liblzma 5.2.2

You can find more info about `xz` by doing [`man xz`](https://ss64.com/bash/xz.html).

Comment: Please, be aware this thread has been read 104k times to date. Be sure to add something distinctive. So far, I don't see any way this post actually contributes to the overall thread. How is it different from writing a one-liner: `xz -k -8e -M 7000MB -T 8 -v whatever.img`? It has been already posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/173841/126755) for instance not exacly the same, but better with the XZ_OPT syntax pointed out. Cheers.

Comment: I sharing my experience in this matter with technical aspects. The example is based on the syntax xz (XZ Utils) 5.2.2 (with man xz) as I write above.

I think the test gives a broader picture of the use of xz and an example for further tests optimizing the compression rate vs performance vs equipment load. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like this to complete faster, using multiple threads, but without slowing down your system while you perform other work, try adding `-Tn` where n is how many threads you want to use, as well as `nice` to demote the compression to idle priority.

Model (for 4 threads):

```
tar c foo/ | nice -n19 xz -9 -T4 > foo.tar.xz
```

Try watching in `top` or `htop` when you do this in a big directory (several GB).  You should hopefully see several `xz` threads with Nice value of 19 (lowest priority).

I've also stripped this down be as terse as sensible, such as: the `-f -` in other answers is simply not needed, since `tar`'s default output is stdout.

You can `nice` the tar process also, but I've never found it necessary, as `xz` always bottlenecks the CPU for the pipeline.

Practical note, I rarely use `xz -9` for anything, not so much due to CPU or time, but because of the high memory demands.  Take a look at https://catchchallenger.first-world.info/wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO#Memory_requirements_on_compression.  The `xz` compressor, like `bzip2`, but unlike `gzip`, uses more memory for higher compression factors.  Put that together with that `xz` uses far more memory than any other compressor, you can easily use up 600+ MB of memory.  And if you use the `-T` to enable threaded compression, the memory demands go up even further.  Just something to be aware of, like if you're running some small service on a small VM with 1-2 GB memory, you could inadvertently cause an impact.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X, an alternate approach to pass in the parameter with `tar` is to use a `--options=` flag. For example,

```
tar Jcvf targetFileName.tar.xz --options='compression-level=9' directoryName
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer to your question but you could use one command instead of two:

```
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on archive.7z dir1
```

adds all files from directory "dir1" to archive archive.7z  using  "ultras ettings"

other formats supported are: zip, gzip, bzip2 or tar. for this just replace `7z` after `-t`.

--source `man 7z`

NOTE: **don't** use this command to backup your **system files** except personal files because [the 7z format doesn't store filesystem permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z#Limitations).

Comment: The question was about xz, not about 7z, even though they both use LZMA compression.