# How to use multi-threading for creating and extracting tar.xz

Tags: tar, zip, compression, multithreading

I use

```
tar -cJvf resultfile.tar.xz files_to_compress
```

to create `tar.xz` and

```
tar -xzvf resultfile.tar.xz
```

to extract the archive in current directory. How to use multi threading in both cases?  I don't want to install any utilities.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```bash
tar -c -I 'xz -9 -T0' -f archive.tar.xz [list of files and folders]
```

This compresses a list of files and directories into an `.tar.xz` archive. It does so by specifying the arguments to be passed to the `xz` subprocess, which compresses the tar archive.

This is done using the `-I` argument to tar, which tells `tar` what program to use to compress the tar archive, and what arguments to pass to it. The `-9` tells `xz` to use maximum compression. The `-T0` tells `xz` to use as many threads as you have CPUs.

---

**An update from January, 2024:**

Even when using the multithreading option, `xz` barely scales beyond two threads, besides its compression/decompression performance is relatively low.

I highly recommend using `ZSTD` instead. The command will be:

```bash
tar -c -I 'zstd -22 --ultra --long -T0' -f archive.tar.xz [list of files and folders]
```

Caveats:

- This commands needs a lot of RAM, at the very least 5GB. You may want to reduce the compression level, or remove `ultra/long` options to decrease RAM consumption.
- Threading might not be used if you don't have enough source data (less than 1GB). If you still want to use threading for a small amount of data, decrease the compression level from 22 to say 20.

Comment: On my TAR though, `-I` won't accept arguments, and expects a program only. Maybe you can make a simple shell script that is `exec xz -9 -T0 $*`?

Comment: This program is used for piping, so `$*` is redundant. Also, not sure why you want to use `exec`.

Comment: it is freaking fast and very less filesize

Comment: Warning: If you have many CPUs, this will use a _lot_ of RAM.....

Comment: This returns `tar: Couldn't open xz -9 -T0: No such file or directory` here (macOS). The following from another answer worked: `tar -cf -  list of files and folders| xz -9 -T0 >| archive.tar.T.xz`

Comment: @aaronk6 older versions of tar don't support passing arguments to compressors. Probably MacOS has the same limitation.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `XZ_DEFAULTS` or `XZ_OPT` environment variables:

**XZ_DEFAULTS** is recommended to be used as a system wide configuration, typically set in a shell initialization script.

**XZ_OPT** is for passing options to `xz` when run by a script or tool, e.g. GNU `tar`. See `man xz`.

Example: using multiple threads (`-T0`) and max compression level (`-9`):

`XZ_OPT='-T0 -9' tar -cJf resultfile.tar.xz files_to_compress`

Reference [with a recent GNU tar on bash or derived shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28977/264270), also see the [xz man page](http://manpages.org/xz#environment)

Answer (score 4):

For older tars, this works:

```
tar -cf -  list of files and folders| xz -9 -T0 >| archive.tar.T.xz
```