# how to extract a multi-threading for tar.xz

Tags: ubuntu, tar, xz

I used the following command to compress a drive mounted to a folder. based on [How to use multi-threading for creating and extracting tar.xz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608207/how-to-use-multi-threading-for-creating-and-extracting-tar-xz?newreg=74d55838199142be96a8028c5ebf9717)

```
tar -c -I 'xz -9 -T0' -f archive.tar.xz /var/lib/docker
```

but when I try to extract it I get this:

```
tar -xvf archive.tar.xz
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
tar (GNU tar) 1.30

Comment: I was on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS when I compressed it

Comment: What does `file archive.tar.xz` report? How did you move the archive from the 18.04 system to the 20.04 system?

Comment: I can't manage to recreate the issue that you are seeing (following the steps that you mention). As steeldriver asks, what does `file archive.tar.xz` output?

Comment: i did not move it. just backup, using tar, the docker drive that was mounted to folder /var/lib/docker If I copy the file to my windows system and do a test it passes. how do I check wat it reports?

Comment: when i use file archive.tar.xz it say  "dockerbackup22052022.tar.xz: empty"

Comment: dump the file is empty! oboy. I will copy back the downloaded file and see if it then extracts.